What is the current teaching on the way disfellowshipped people are to be treated by Jehovah's Witnesses?
I recently met in the street a JW who I like to talk to and he told me that the teaching on the treatment of those who have been disfellowshipped has changed. They are now not so ostracised as they once were; at least that is my current understanding.
So my questions are:

What change has been made?
When was the change made?
What was the previous teaching?
What is the current teaching?
Is there any practical reason or current situation which anyone thinks has precipitated the change?

Thanks

ostracised* Is what I think you meant to spell. :)

I have found some information on this and need to go over it to ensure I get all of it straight in my head to provide an easy-to-understand explanation.

@agarza - thanks in advance Agarza!!

Ther was an update video that addressed some slight changes regarding saying a brief greeting to a df’d person.  that info will eventually make it into print with additional clarification.

@Kristopher - Ah, thanks, as recent as that!  Do you know if this greeting is only inside a Kingdom Hall intended only for those who are in the process of seeking to be restored, or is it for any disfellowshipped person (on the street, as it were)?

@AndrewShanks - It's up to the individual's conscience how they behave when meeting a former JW - the location and setting don't matter. The only exception is those who are known to be disfellowshipped JWs and who actively/openly oppose biblical doctrine and views (known as apostates or antichrists) - they are still to be fully shunned. Those are the ones JWs now understand from the context (2 John 6-11) not even to greet.

@JsWitness - Thanks Js!  When did the video come out and any idea when the full written explanation will be in print?

@AndrewShanks - March 15th 2024 as part of the Governing Body update #2 (https://www.jw.org/en/news/region/global/2024-Governing-Body-Update-2/) starting with the 12:20 timestamp. A series of Watchtower Study edition articles are still to come out - my guess is by the end of 2024 or the beginning of 2025.

@JsWitness - It would good to have an answer when the issue is in print.  Many thanks so far!!

@AndrewShanks The link to the Watchtower study article above (posted half an hour ago by Kristopher) is given in my answer below, posted on 12 August 2024.  That Watchtower article was available in August, when I found it.

@Kristopher - thanks.  I've read the article.  Where it says "Bible-trained conscience"  "Watchtower-trained conscience" is better.  The article is giving permission to JWs to make a decision of their own, on how to interact with the df'd. Why would a Christian who understands the Bible need or want permission from men to put it into practice?  The Watchtower is effectively saying Do not obey God until/unless we give you permission!

[For readers to better understand some terms I will be using, I have supplied the definitions and sources for these. I have also changed the order of the questions originally asked to provide a better flow of information.]
Definitions:

Disfellowshipping (or expelling) - "The judicial excommunication, or disfellowshipping, of delinquents from membership and association in a community or organization." (Source: Insight on the Scriptures: Expelling, p. 787)
Governing Body - "a small group of mature Christians who provide direction for Jehovah's Witnesses worldwide." (Source: What Is the Governing Body of Jehovah's Witnesses?)
Serious sin - This refers to "sexual immorality, idolatry, thievery, extortion, murder, and spiritism.​—1 Corinthians 6:9, 10; Revelation 21:8." (Source: Why Disfellowshipping Is a Loving Provision)

What change has been made?
In short, the change deals with how cases of wrongdoing are handled within the congregation.
What was the previous teaching?
If a baptized member of the congregation committed a serious sin and was unrepentant of their actions, a judicial committee of elders could come to the decision that the individual needed to be disfellowshipped. Afterward, the elders would explain what the person needs to do to be reinstated as a congregation member. After this, the elders would periodically (usually once a year) check on the individual to see if there was a change in their attitude. No other efforts would be made to assist them.
At a subsequent meeting, a brief announcement would be made to the congregation stating that the named individual was no longer a member of Jehovah's Witnesses. Congregation members are admonished to not socialize or speak with this person. This is based on 1 Corinthians 5:11 and 2 John 9-11.
When was the change made? What is the current teaching?
On March 15, 2024, the video titled "2024 Governing Body Update #2" was presented by Mark Sanderson which discusses "some new information regarding the way we'll handle cases of wrongdoing in the Christian congregation." Starting at timestamp 4:00, Sanderson begins discussing a clearer understanding of three scriptures.

2 Timothy 2:24, 25


24 For a slave of the Lord does not need to fight, but needs to be gentle toward all, qualified to teach, showing restraint when wronged, 25 instructing with mildness those not favorably disposed. Perhaps God may give them repentance leading to an accurate knowledge of truth, [bold mine]

Sanderson focuses on the phrase "those not favorably disposed" and references the study note for verse 25 which says "Paul uses a Greek word that in this context refers to people who resist Christian teachings or who place themselves in opposition to them." The modern-day application "could include brothers and sisters in the congregation who disregard Scriptural counsel and become involved in serious wrongdoing." Another study note for verse 25 states "When a Christian elder mildly corrects or instructs 'those not favorably disposed,' the good result may be repentance, or 'a change of mind.'" Previously, the elders would meet with the individual only once. "However, the Governing Body has decided that the committee may decide to meet with the person more than once. Why? At Revelation 2:21, regarding "that woman Jezebel," Jesus said: "I gave her time to repent."" So while the wrongdoer is removed from the congregation, the elders are to encourage the person to repent.

1 Corinthians 5:13


while God judges those outside? "Remove the wicked person from among yourselves." [bold mine]

While the Bible is clear on what is to be done with the wrongdoer, they "won't be left hopeless. The committee will not simply explain what steps he can take to be welcomed back into the congregation. What else will they do? The elders will explain that they'd like to meet with the individual again after a few months to see if he's had a change of heart. If the individual is willing to meet, the elders will make a warm appeal for him to repent and return." Previously, it was up to the individual to initiate any return to the congregation. Now, in imitation of Jehovah's mercy, the elders will try to help as many as possible to let wrongdoers know they can return.
Sanderson reminds us of the counsel at 1 Corinthians 5:11 that "we don't socialize with those who are removed from the congregation. However, that does not mean that a Christian could not invite a disfellowshipped person to attend a congregation meeting. That disfellowshipped person could be a relative, a former Bible student, or someone we were close to in the past."

2 John 9-11


9 Everyone who pushes ahead and does not remain in the teaching of the Christ does not have God. The one who does remain in this teaching is the one who has both the Father and the Son. 10 If anyone comes to you and does not bring this teaching, do not receive him into your homes or say a greeting to him. 11 For the one who says a greeting to him is a sharer in his wicked works. [bold mine]

Sanderson brings out, "In examining the context of those verses, the Governing Body has concluded that the apostle John was really describing apostates and others who actively promoted wrong conduct. For good reason, John strongly directed Christians not even to greet such a person because of his contaminating influence. Therefore, if a disfellowshipped individual is a known apostate or someone who actively promotes wrongdoing, the elders would not visit him. Neither would individual Christians greet such a person or invite him to attend a congregation meeting."
In addition to this video, the August 2024 Watchtower—Study Edition contains a series of articles that will be studied from October 7–November 10, 2024. The last article "Help for Those Who Are Removed From the Congregation" covers the same information as the video but with more detail and scriptural support.
Is there any practical reason or current situation which anyone thinks has precipitated the change?
From time to time, the Governing Body will review topics for a better understanding of Jehovah's ways. One of the recent topics was Jehovah's mercy and how it is seen in previous accounts in the Bible. As mentioned at the beginning of the video, Sanderson mentions that the Governing Body in "prayerful study, meditation, and discussions, we've focused our attention on how Jehovah has dealt with people who engaged in serious sin."
[All scripture quotations from the New World Translation of the Holy Scriptures (Study Edition)]

Further to the excellent answer provided by Agarza explaining the changes that now take effect regarding the treatment of disfellowshipped Witnesses, this article published August 2024, and to be studied in Kingdom Halls in October this year, specifically deals with your main question.  Here is a summary of some of the main points.
Paragraphs 10 and 11 discuss how the elders may reinstate Witnesses who were disfellowshipped in the past but who no longer practice the sin for which they were removed from the congregation and who wish to return.

When a sinner manifests repentance and abandons his wrong course, he can be reinstated without delay.—2 Cor. 2:6-8.

Caution must be exercised if a person was guilty of child abuse or apostasy or if he schemed to end a marriage.  Apostasy is when a baptised Witnesses openly disagrees with the teachings of the organisation and who speaks out against them. Fidelity within a marriage and morality are also viewed (rightly) as essential.  True repentance and evidence that a wrong course has been abandoned must be manifest before the elders could reinstate such persons.
Perhaps the most significant change is to be found in paragraph 14:

14 Does what we have considered mean that we would completely ignore a person who has been removed from the congregation? Not necessarily. Certainly, we would not socialize with him. But Christians can use their Bible-trained conscience in deciding whether to invite a person who was removed from the congregation—perhaps a relative or someone they were close to previously—to attend a congregation meeting. What if he attends? In the past, we would not greet such a person. Here again, each Christian needs to use his Bible-trained conscience in this matter. Some may feel comfortable with greeting or welcoming the person to the meeting. However, we would not have an extended conversation or socialize with the individual.


Christians can use their Bible-trained conscience when deciding whether to invite a person who has been removed from the congregation to a meeting or to welcome the individual to the meeting with a simple greeting.

Previously, any member who was disfellowshipped for immorality, apostasy or being found guilty of child abuse, would be totally shunned, not only by the congregation but by their own family. This change shows a real softening of attitudes from the leaders.
The exception to this relaxation of the rules does not apply to apostates and those who actively promote wrong conduct:

Therefore, if a person is actively promoting apostate teachings or other wrongdoing, the elders would not arrange to visit him. Of course, there is hope that he will come to his senses. Until that happens, though, we would neither greet such a person nor invite him to attend a congregation meeting.


We will no longer refer to such ones as being disfellowshipped. In harmony with Paul’s words recorded at 1 Corinthians 5:13, we will now refer to them as being removed from the congregation.


According to the Bible, an unforgivable sin is not a particular type of sin but a sin that is committed with a hardened attitude that is permanently opposed to God. Whether a person has committed such a sin is not for us to judge.

Apart from the Watchtower Study Article 35 (above) I found an older official source from Insight on the Scriptures  This answers your question about the previous teachings:

Some of the offenses that could merit disfellowshipping from the Christian congregation are fornication, adultery, homosexuality, greed, extortion, thievery, lying, drunkenness, reviling, spiritism, murder, idolatry, apostasy, and the causing of divisions in the congregation. (1Co 5:9-13; 6:9, 10; Tit 3:10, 11; Re 21:8) Mercifully, one promoting a sect is warned a first and a second time before such disfellowshipping action is taken against him. In the Christian congregation, the principle enunciated in the Law applies, namely, that two or three witnesses must establish evidence against the accused one. (1Ti 5:19) Those who have been convicted of a practice of sin are reproved Scripturally before the “onlookers,” for example, those who testified concerning the sinful conduct, so that they too may all have a healthy fear of such sin.—1Ti 5:20; see REPROOF.


The Christian congregation is also admonished by Scripture to stop socializing with those who are disorderly and not walking correctly but who are not deemed deserving of complete expulsion. Paul wrote the Thessalonian congregation concerning such: “Stop associating with him, that he may become ashamed. And yet do not be considering him as an enemy, but continue admonishing him as a brother.”—2Th 3:6, 11, 13-15.


However, regarding any who were Christians but later repudiated the Christian congregation or were expelled from it, the apostle Paul commanded: “Quit mixing in company with” such a one; and the apostle John wrote: “Never receive him into your homes or say a greeting to him.”—1Co 5:11; 2Jo 9, 10.


Those who have been expelled may be received back into the congregation if they manifest sincere repentance. (2Co 2:5-8) This also is a protection to the congregation, preventing it from being overreached by Satan in swinging from condoning wrongdoing to the other extreme, becoming harsh and unforgiving.—2Co 2:10, 11.

Your final question on what may have precipitated the changes, may be answered in this article
There is also the fact that global % growth has diminished over the past decade (from 2.4% in 2011 to 1.3% in 2023) and that in some countries, growth has been negative. In 2020 there was a global decrease of 0.6% and a decrease of 3% in the U.K. alone.  I do not wish to speculate or be uncharitable, but I have access to statistics from previous Annual Year Books to verify this.
A less harsh approach to disfellowshipping and shunning is only to be welcomed.
I don't know if this is an official statistic from the 2024 Service Year Report but there has been a 43% increase in "those who returned to Jehovah" which suggests that this less harsh approach is having positive results.
For the latest statistics from the 2024 worldwide service year report, please see the comments (below) from Kristopher.

The speculation about this being in response to diminishing growth is purely your opinion. Covid 19 came on the scene in 2020 btw

@Kristopher I acknowledge that Covid 19 had a negative impact worldwide, but the fact remains that between 2011 and 2023 annual growth has declined from 2.4% to 1.3%. It will be interesting to see what the stats are when the latest figures are released in August.

I predict an all time record high of active publisher.  And a newly baptized number around 2%

@Kristopher Well, if that turns out to be the case, I will edit my post accordingly :-)

@Kristopher Can you confirm that the average number of active publishers has gone up from 8,625,042 in the 2023 report to 8,828,124 in 2024 report (an increase of 203,082). Also that those baptized went up by 26,789 (from 269,517 to 296,297)? I'm no good with maths, so would that be an increase of 2% - am happy to edit my post accordingly.

On November 13, 2024, the Service Committee of the Governing Body shared highlights of the 2024 worldwide service year report with the Bethel family. It was announced that an average of 8,828,124 publishers shared in preaching the good news each month, a 2.4 percent increase. And for the first time, the peak number of publishers surpassed 9 million, with a total of 9,043,460! Also heartwarming was the 43.2 percent increase in those who returned to Jehovah, with 65,816 who were reinstated! Other increases that were announced included the following: cont.

Cont. A total of 296,267 were baptized, which represents a 9.9 percent increase over the 2023 service year. An average of 7,480,146 Bible studies were conducted each month, up 2.7 percent. Memorial attendance worldwide was 21,119,442, an increase of 3.2 percent. The number of regular pioneers increased by 6.8 percent to 1,651,698. And the number of auxiliary pioneers increased by 17.5 percent, with an average of 867,502 serving in that capacity each month.

@Kristopher Greatly appreciated. I was unable to access the 2024 statistics from the official JW.org web site.  I will now update my records accordingly.

The info was up as a news tidbit for a couple days. Full report wil likely be in near future.

@Kristopher Yes, I picked up some info but not anything official.  Will wait till the full report is published. I am delighted to know that the G.B. is making serious efforts to bring those who have repented back into fellowship. Pity it's taken them so long though.

“Pity it's taken them so long though.”    Fortunately only God’s judgment of individual hearts really counts in the end.

@Kristopher True, and that applies to the GB and the Elders who imposed draconian punishments onto people who disagreed with them. But if you believe salvation can only be found within Jehovah's earthly organisation, then you will toe the line and do as you are told for fear of being kicked out and being shunned. That has been going on for 100 years. Still, better late than never, eh?
